# Sqoop Teradata Connector issue - Error: The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am facing issue with Teradata connector for Sqoop, when i am trying to import table from Teradata View. I have only access for Views.

but somehow when sqoop job starts it is trying to create a table in Teradata DB which i am accessing but dont have right to create any table in that DB/schema

I am getting below Error

```
 13/05/31 03:40:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:     com.teradata.hadoop.exception.TeradataHadoopSQLException: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.01] [Error 3524] [SQLState 42000] The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database EDWABSVIEWS.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:307)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:102)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:298)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:179)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:120)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:111)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:372)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:314)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecute(TDStatement.java:277)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.execute(TDStatement.java:1087)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataConnection.executeDDL(TeradataConnection.java:379)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataConnection.createTable(TeradataConnection.java:1655)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.createStageTable(TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.java:233)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.setup(TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.java:87)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataImportJob.run(TeradataImportJob.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataImportJob.doSubmitJob(TeradataImportJob.java:173)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:208)
    at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importTable(TeradataConnManager.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)

    at    com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.createStageTable(TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.java:243)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.setup(TeradataPartitionStageInputProcessor.java:87)
    at com.teradata.hadoop.TeradataImportJob.run(TeradataImportJob.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataImportJob.doSubmitJob(TeradataImportJob.java:173)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:208)
    at     org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importTable(TeradataConnManager.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Please assist.

Comment: I have found one property for Teradata connector -D sqoop.teradata.import.use.temporary.table=false, it is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudera Connector for Teradata 1.1.1 do not support imports from views as is documented in [limitations](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Connectors/Cloudera-Connector-for-Teradata/cctd_topic_6.html) section of the user guide.

The connector will try to create temporary tables in order to provide all or nothing semantics, which I'm expecting is the reason for the exception. If you do not have such privileges on the main database, you can instruct the connector to create the staging tables in any other database where you have enough privileges. Please check out the [User guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Connectors/Cloudera-Connector-for-Teradata/cctd_topic_4.html) for further instructions.

Comment: I am using TD connector from Hortonwork, is it a similar implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have specified the `split.by.partition` method and your table is not partitioned or if you enabled `--staging-force`, the TeraData connector will create a stage table by default into the specified DB in the connection URL.

From Cloudera documentation:

> If your input table is not partitioned, the connector creates a partitioned staging table and executes an INSERT into SELECT query to move data from the source table into the staging table. Subsequently, each mapper transfers data from one partition, resulting in a single AMP operation. With a single AMP, you can use a large number of mappers to obtain optimal performance. The amount of available permanent space must be as large as your source table and the amount of spool space required to execute the SELECT queries.
>   If your table is already partitioned, no extra staging table is created. However, you can force the connector to re-partition your data using the --staging-force parameter to achieve better performance. Without forcing repartition of the data, this method opens all-AMP operation, so you should use between 20 and 30 mappers. If your source table is a PI table, and your split by column is the table’s primary key, the connector creates a single AMP operation, and you can use high number of mappers.

To solve that you have to avoid staging, either switch to `split.by.value` or `split.by.hash` or you could specify a different DB for the staging table (`--staging-database`) on which you have `CREATE TABLE` permission.

Furthermore, consider that the connector will try to create a view whenever you have a free form query (`--query`) and multiple mappers. To workaround the `CREATE VIEW` permission error either you specify `--table <TABLE_NAME>` and you load the whole table, you can still specify which columns (`--columns`) and the WHERE filter (`--where`), or you have to get rid of parallelism using `--num-mappers 1`.

I personally think there should be a property to enable/disable the creation of views. If you are performing an Import Data workflow you should not be required to create views as well as staging table.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same error when I tried to use `--split-by` argument along with free form query `--query` argument. Then I replaced `--split-by` with `--num-mappers 1`, to force SQOOP run it in one process. And then that error went away.

I am assuming that `--split-by` will tried to create temporary files/views where single mapper process might not.

Here is a template that I am using:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:teradata://<host>/Database=<dbname> \
--username <username> \
--password <password> \
--hive-import \
--hive-table <hivetablename> \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--num-mappers 1 \
--target-dir <hdfspath> \
--query "<sqlquery> and \$CONDITIONS"
```